# Testing bot directly with ConnectorClient without framework emulator

Tags: c#, botframework

Can anyone give a specific C# example of sending a message to a bot and waiting for the reply? I'm trying to test a bot without using the emulator, so I can have more control and see more details. I've read documentation about the different REST APIs, but I'm really not sure how to specifically implement these in a C# program.

I think I can start it with:

```
using Microsoft.Bot.Connector;
var client = new ConnectorClient(appID, appSecret);
```

But I don't know where to go from there. I want to test sending a message from a user to a bot, and then waiting for the bot to respond, and then displaying the response message.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is a `ConnectorClient`? Is this a C# library/Nuget package you are using?

Comment: It's defined in `Microsoft.Bot.Connector` but I can't find proper documentation for how to use it.

Comment: In that case, it looks like this: http://docs.botframework.com/connector/getstarted/#navtitle should be very helpful to you.

Comment: Yes, I've read through that page many times. As the question said, I'm trying to write my own client program, not use the provided bot emulator.

Comment: Hm, it's a bit confusing then, so you don't want to use the `ConnectorClient` class?

Comment: I do want to use it, since I believe it's used to send and receive messages, but I don't know how, so I'm looking for a specific example of how to do so.

Comment: Then it is more confusing, I see sections of the previous documentation titled `Replying to a message`, `Starting a conversation`, `Composing Messages`, `Message Types`, etc. None of these sections explain how to "send an receive messages" as you say?

Comment: Not sending and receiving in a single program.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with direct API. That is not much difficult. Please browse the link below.

[Example code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783836/how-to-connect-to-microsoft-bot-framework-from-android-cilent/37785636#37785636)