# Calling Bot api from another REST service api

Tags: botframework

we have a scenario , wherein we need to call the Bot service from another REST based api .
What is the best way to achieve the same.
Is directline api the most probable solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes,

Direct line API is the best solution for this. Because it provide almost every aspect to connect with the bot framework via as the REST based API. If you are looking for a sample to implement the Direct API with any application refer below link,

[Develop Bot with Direct Line API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783836/how-to-connect-to-microsoft-bot-framework-from-android-cilent/37785636#37785636)