# Microsoft BotFramework for private apps

Tags: c#, artificial-intelligence, botframework, chatbot, botconnector

I would like to use Microsoft Bot Framework to build a chatbot for an app that I am building, and I do not want it to be working in Skype, Facebook or any other channels.

Is that possible? And are there are cost involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to connect your bot into your own chat application, best way is to use [Direct Line Rest API](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline/#navtitle). So disable everything except `Direct Line`

For an example about how you can use Direct Line API please refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783836/how-to-connect-to-microsoft-bot-framework-from-android-cilent/37785636#37785636).

> Another important thing is to use Bot Framework V3. Not the previous
>   versions. The team made changes in the new version by implementing
>   enhancements for the future. So those features and structure are much different
>   than previous versions.

This means V1 is deprecated, meaning almost all of your code would need to be rewritten for V3.

---

There is no cost for you to enable or disable any channels right now. In the below picture, [Bot Framework Developer Portal](https://dev.botframework.com/) gives you the full control to add new channels or delete them from you bot.

[image]

Comment: I agree with @codelahiru.  Note, you can disable the two auto-provisioned channels (Skype, Webchat) by editing them and using the red reauthorize button.  DirectLine would be the appropriate channel to work with if you want to own the client and bot ends of the conversation.