# How to communicate the web service to bot framework directly?

Tags: node.js, botframework, skype-bots

I was working with bot framework from last week. implemented the node.js SDK for skype chat.

Sometimes I need synchronise call between bot and API. Is it possible for service to contact bot directly or is it just one way?

Please guide me if any one have suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You should look into [DirectLine](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline3/#navtitle).

> The Direct Line API is a simple REST API for connecting directly to a
>   single bot. This API is intended for developers writing their own
>   client applications, web chat controls, or mobile apps that will talk
>   to their bot.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37783836/how-to-connect-to-microsoft-bot-framework-from-android-cilent/37785636#37785636) you will find more information about how to use it and here there is [Node.js sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/core-DirectLine) using DirectLine to talk with the bot.

Comment: thanks @Ezequiel Jadib I will try with your solution. Hope it will work for me