# Bot framework connection with custom chat window UI

Tags: node.js, bots, botframework, chatbot, web-chat

I have created a bot program in node.js using Microsoft bot framework. Now I want to connect that bot program with my custom chat window UI (index.html) built in HTML, CSS & JS and deployed over an intranet network. I have already created a local express server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to communicate the web service to bot framework directly?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40904833/how-to-communicate-the-web-service-to-bot-framework-directly)

Comment: Hi Ezequiel ,
The link is useful but I don't want to register my bot to Microsoft BOT framework because "I want to deploy it to an intranet network." Is there any option to achieve it without Direct Line API ? if "NO" then is it mandatory to register BOT to Microsoft BOT framework. ?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40888489/bot-framework-without-azure-possible